# Output power of an actuator - General definition

Tags: power, actuator

I'm looking for a general definition of the output power of an actuator. Can you suggest me any book or paper or education website where I can find it please?

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT

I read the paper "Youqi Wang 2004 - Deformation mechanisms of electrostrictive graft elastomer" where I found the locution "output power". I'd like to know a general definition of the output power of an actuator.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Gennaro Arguzzi, but I'm afraid that it's not clear what you're asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, and what you found. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Hello @MarkBooth, can I ask also questions about theory?

Comment: Absolutely, See the [help/on-topic] for more information on what is on topic here.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like there is a bit of a mismatch between your question on the "general definition of the output power of an actuator" and the image. Perhaps if you could edit your question to say where the screen grab came from and why you think it might be relevant to your question, it might help us understand what you are trying find out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @MarkBooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads to me like the author is stating that a stiffer material means it could make an actuator with more output power, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Maybe they mean a more efficient actuator? Actuator output power is just any definition of mechanical power; either a force times the linear speed or a torque times the rotational speed.

A stiffer material may mean that the input power is transmitted more efficiently to the output end of the actuator because the motion isn't "consumed" by flex or deformation in the actuator material.

More efficient actuators then would imply that you could make an actuator that had the same weight but a higher output power, but that's *specific* power, or the power-to-weight ratio. This may be what the author meant - stiffer materials could lead to actuators with greater specific power output.

You should try to contact the author(s) for more information! I've only tried contacting authors a couple times, but I've gotten really friendly responses every time I have.

Comment: Hello @Chuck, thank you so much for your extremely clear explanation and for the suggestion.